# Programatically request permission to use cross-site cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, browser

I'm using https://utteranc.es to put comments on my docs website (https://squirrelly.js.org), but my browser blocks cross-site cookies so it logs users out whenever they navigate to a new page.

I know Brave Browser and I think several other browsers block cross-site cookies by default. Is there a way for me to request that users allow cross-site cookies, with an API like the one that allows sites to request access to Desktop Notifications?

**Note: I know users can manually enable cross-site cookies in site settings. Is there any way that *I*, the site dev, can make comments work for my users?**

*If there are any other ways to achieve the same result, I'll gladly take them*

Comment: Security measures generally cannot be controlled by code from a web site; that would pretty much defeat the purpose.

Comment: @Pointy but websites can request permission from the user to use the webcam and microphone...

Comment: Yes, that's built in to browsers; facilities for cookies generally aren't because some sites would drive people crazy.

Comment: I just had to log into SchoolSoft with my school-provided Micro$oft account and it suddenly popped up a Firefox permission dialog asking me if the site is allowed to use cookies from login[.]live[.]com and after clicking "Yes" the login proceeded successfully because I had already logged in to Office365 with the same M$ account. I think something like that is feasible in every browser, otherwise Micro$oft wouldn't implement its use on their site just for Firefox, they have their own browser and Chrome is much more popular.